# AngularJs template tags not evaluating sometimes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django-templates, angularjs-directive

I'm wondering why templating tag `[[ opt.option ]]` is not evaluating to a value sometimes in the following code

`<span ng-repeat="opt in options">`
`<button  ng-click="button = [[ opt.option ]]" ng-class="{ active : button == [[ opt.option ]] } ng-cloak>`
`<i class="icon-tick visible-in-active" ></i>[[ opt.option ]]`
`</button>` 
 `</span>`

The buttons are are being outputted with names meaning the template tag for naming the button is working but when I click any of the buttons, none is being active meaning the  templating tags for `ng-click` and `ng-class` are not evaluating. why is this?

**Edit**
I'm using django so I had to override {{}} with [[]] since django uses these tags too {{}}

I want to achieve [THIS.](http://jsfiddle.net/7Habz/) when a button is clicked, it becomes active and the previous active one becomes inactive. This is what am getting [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3q6N/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of ng-click and ng-class you don't need to use data binding operators. You can just say :

```
<button ng-click="button = opt.option" ng-class="{ active : button == opt.option }">
```

Also the data binding operator in angular is {{ }} not [[ ]].

Finally, you have a typo and have not closed the opening button tag (you're missing the last '">')

**Update** - as pointed out the binding operator can be customized so this is not actually an issue.

**Update** - here's an example plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/t4hmRmJCI22bjqMe1Jc4?p=preview

Comment: It should be noted that this is customizable. He could have changed it to [[]] from {{}}.

Comment: @JonathanRowny never knew that! Thanks for pointing it out. Any practical use for that feature?

Comment: I'm sure there is but not that I can think of... maybe you just hate squiggly brackets? There's an example of how to do it here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolateProvider

Comment: It just occurred to me that the "practical use" is that he's using Django templating and doesn't want to escape all those mustaches that Django templates use. So [[]] == client side and {{}} == server side. We're so off topic!

Comment: @ksimons I've tried that and still not working. Check the fiddles I have added please.

Comment: Your second fiddle doesn't have anything in it, so it's hard to help

Comment: I've added an example plunk. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use {{ }} not [[ ]]

Comment: He probably has overridden $interpolateProvider to use [[]] instead of  {{}}. It wouldn't ever work if this wasn't done.

Comment: adding an explaination would be nice.

Comment: Interesting didn't know that :) Though I don't think he changed, he would have said

Comment: @EranH. I'm actually using django so I had to override {{}} with [[]] since django uses these tags too {{}}. I have Edited the question please.